# Creating a custom popup with Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

Below is the code for my Tinymce textarea

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        height : 350,
            plugins: [
                    "link image lists preview anchor"
            ],
        toolbar: " image bold italic | formatselect | undo redo | cut copy paste | bullist numlist | undo redo | link unlink dummyimg | preview",
        menubar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        setup : function(ed) {
        // Add a custom button
        ed.addButton('dummyimg', {
            title : 'Add image',
            image : 'resources/images/img.jpg',
            onclick : function() {
                if($('#imageupload').val()){
                  ed.focus();
                  ed.selection.setContent('<img src="<%=strWebhost%>/news_cms/resources/images/dummyimg.jpg" />');
                } else{
                  alert("Please select an image.");
                }

                }
            });
        },
        onchange_callback: function(editor) {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            $("#" + editor.id).valid();
        }
   });
```

I have added a custom button called `dummyimg` which adds a predefined image into the tinymce container. My requirement is, i need a pop window like the one shown below which enables me to add only a image `title` using the custom button.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

this example should get your started:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea.editor',
    menubar : false,
    statusbar : false,
    toolbar: "dummyimg | bold italic underline strikethrough | formatselect | fontsizeselect | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | link image | cut copy paste | undo redo | code",
    plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview code',
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.addButton('dummyimg', {
            title : 'Edit Image',
            image : 'img/example.gif',
            onclick : function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Edit image',
                    body: [
                        {type: 'textbox', name: 'source', label: 'Source'}
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {    
                        ed.focus();
                        ed.selection.setContent('<pre class="language-' + e.data.language + ' line-numbers"><code>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</code></pre>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Obviously you'd need to edit the `ed.selection.setContent` line in the `onsubmit` to suit your own needs, as well as setting the correct `toolbar` and `plugins` settings.

Comment: Can you explain what's onsubmit? Also, how to get the content of `source` textbox? Thanks

Comment: @Abdillah just go like : e.data.source ->> e.data.[name]

Comment: The documentation isn't very helpful, so I went ahead and wrote an article listing the different widgets and containers layout available: http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2016/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-in-tinymce-4

Answer (score 1):

While this question is old.. I am replying to your other question ( I can't comment yet).

"how to get the content of source textbox?"

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
  console.log(e.data.source)
}
```